# SELECT RAND AS field while selecting other values modified by field

Tags: mysql, sql, random, subquery, selection

I tried to simplify this, so its more of an example of the actual code. I want to get a random number and use it to modify several values, but I need all the values to be modified by the same random number.

my general SELECT statement goes something like:

```
SELECT id, value1, value2
```

and i want each value to be multiplied by the same random number

I know this wont work, because then it will use 2 different random numbers:

```
SELECT id, value1 * FLOOR(RAND()*10), value2 * FLOOR(RAND()*10)
```

So I want something like this, but this is wrong, since I have no idea what I'm doing:

```
SELECT id, FLOOR(RAND()*10) AS rmod, value1 * rmod, value2 * rmod
```

I definitely need to read up on the more advanced selection methods in SQL, maybe someone can point me in the right direction? Sub Queries I think? I know I can do something like create a random number in my PHP code, and then just splice that into the SQL command string, but I was looking for an SQL only solution specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
select @r:=rand(),@r;
```

The first call to rand() sets the variable @r which can be used in subsequent expressions. In your example:

```
SELECT id, value1 * FLOOR(@rand:=RAND()*10), value2 * FLOOR(@rand*10)
```

Comment: SELECT @r:=FLOOR(RAND()*10),@r; SELECT id, value1 * @r, value2 * @r; works great!! thanks